# WebRTC Google Nest Cam Live Stream Javascript Video

Tags: javascript, google-api, stream, webrtc

I have a problem for access live streem of google nest cam Battery. I would get the stream in my web site. For this I use JavaScript. Nut sometimes i have the video fo stream and sometimes I can't get the stream. I doesn't get any error.

Code Javascript-HTML that I use :

```
<h1>Google Nest Cam Live Stream</h1>
    <video id="webCamVideo" autoplay playsinline width="360" height="240"></video>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: [
        'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
        'stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302',
      ],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};

let peerConnection = null;
let remoteStream = null;

async function startFeed() {

  peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  const token = '<?php echo($_COOKIE["acto"]); ?>';

  const videoobject = document.getElementById("webCamVideo");

  remoteStream = new MediaStream();
  videoobject.srcObject = remoteStream;

  // Watch for new tracks from remote stream; add to video stream
  peerConnection.ontrack = event => {
    event.streams[0].getTracks().forEach(track => {
        remoteStream.addTrack(track);
    });
  };

  // Data Channel Required by the SDM API.
  peerConnection.createDataChannel("dataSendChannel");


  // Create the offer.
  const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer({
     offerToReceiveAudio: true, 
     offerToReceiveVideo: true 
  });
  peerConnection.addTransceiver('audio', { direction: 'recvonly' });
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
  
  // Safari doesn't respect the parameter requests of createOffer above, so let's fudge the offer ourselves!
  let offerSdp = offer.sdp;
  offerSdp = offerSdp.replace('a=sendrecv','a=recvonly');

  // Now, send request for SDP connection
  const url = 'https://smartdevicemanagement.googleapis.com/v1/enterprises/PROJECTID/devices/DEVICEID:executeCommand';
  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "command": "sdm.devices.commands.CameraLiveStream.GenerateWebRtcStream",
      "params" : {
        "offerSdp" : offerSdp
      }      
    })
  };
  const response = await fetch(url, options);
  
  // Process the response.
  const data = await response.json();
  let answerSdp = data.results.answerSdp;
  
  // Now start the feed using the answer
  const answer = new RTCSessionDescription({type: 'answer', sdp: answerSdp});
  await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
  

}

startFeed();

    </script>
```

How I can resolve this?

I need your help.
Thanks.